# Eclipse EditorPart save on partDeactivated

Tags: eclipse, focus, eclipse-rcp

My problem is that I have a custom application, using EditorParts, which are persisted to a database. The user can open several Editors, and switch between them. I need to ask the user to save any unsaved changes in an Editor, before switching to the next Editor (or else close it).

I have created an IPartListener2, and I receive the partDeactivated notification. If isDirty()==true, I bring up a MessageDialog asking to save or not; because I want to call editor.doSave().

My problem is that does not work. I never see the MessageDialog, because another partDeactivated fires. I guess, this is caused by the MessageDialog over the Editor.

I have researched [How to listen to lose focus event of a part in Eclipse E4 RCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33342823/how-to-listen-to-lose-focus-event-of-a-part-in-eclipse-e4-rcp), but that did not help me.

thanks to help a e4 beginner

```java
public class DatasetAttachmentEditor {
        ... // code here
    @Override
    public void init(IEditorSite site, IEditorInput input)  throws PartInitException {
        ... // code here
        site.getPage().addPartListener(new EditorsPartListener(this));
    }
}

public class EditorsPartListener implements IPartListener2 {

    private IEditorPart editor;

    public EditorsPartListener(IEditorPart editor) {
        this.editor = editor;
    }

    @Override
    public void partClosed(IWorkbenchPartReference partRef) {
        if (partRef.getPage().getActiveEditor().getClass().getName().equals(editor.getClass().getName())) {
            partRef.getPage().removePartListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void partDeactivated(IWorkbenchPartReference partRef) {

        if (!partRef.getClass().getName().equals("org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference")) {
            System.out.println("partDeactivated: not a Editor="+partRef.getClass().getName());
            return;
        }

        if (!editor.isDirty()) {
            // if the editor is not dirty - do nothing
            return;
        }

        // ask if to save
        int choice = EditorPartSaveDialog(partRef.getPage().getActiveEditor());
        if(choice == MessageDialog.OK) {
            // save the Editor
            try {
                ProgressMonitorDialog progress = new ProgressMonitorDialog(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell());                
                progress.setCancelable(false);
                progress.run(false, false, new IRunnableWithProgress() {
                    @Override
                    public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
                        // do the save
                        editor.doSave(monitor);
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        else {
            // don't save: just close it
            partRef.getPage().closeEditor(editor, false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void partActivated(IWorkbenchPartReference partRef) {
    }

    @Override
    public void partBroughtToTop(IWorkbenchPartReference partRef) {
    }

    @Override
    public void partOpened(IWorkbenchPartReference partRef) {
    }

    @Override
    public void partHidden(IWorkbenchPartReference partRef) {
    }

    @Override
    public void partVisible(IWorkbenchPartReference partRef) {
    }

    @Override
    public void partInputChanged(IWorkbenchPartReference partRef) {
    }

    /**
     * Asks the user to Save changes
     * @param editor
     * @return MessageDialog.OK to save, MessageDialog.CANCEL otherwise
     */
    private int EditorPartSaveDialog(IEditorPart editor) {

        // If save confirmation is required ..
        String message = NLS.bind("''{0}'' has been modified. Save changes?", LegacyActionTools.escapeMnemonics(editor.getTitle()));

        // Show a dialog.
        MessageDialog d = new MessageDialog(
                            Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell(),
                            "Save Editor", null, message,
                            MessageDialog.QUESTION,
                            0,
                            "Save",// MessageDialog 0x0 (OK)
                            "Don't Save: close"// MessageDialog 0x1 (CANCEL)
                        )
        return d.open();
    }
}
```

Comment: `IPartListener2` is part of 3.x compatibility mode, not e4. If you are using things like `EditorPart` you are writing 3.x compatibility mode code. In any case show us your code.

Comment: I think forcing your users to save changes just because they are switching to another part is a bad idea. Editors in RCP are designed to let the user choose when editor content should be saved. Why did you choose to work against the platform's design?

Comment: @Hermann: I need to validate unique user input, and this is very difficult with only some database records shown in the UI and containing changes - and other elements persisted into the database. The only other way would be to validate against DB and aginst all open instances of the Editor. How can you enumerate the opened editors from an IValidator?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to run your code after the deactivate event has finished. You can do this using `Display.asyncExec`.

Something like:

```java
@Override
public void partDeactivated(IWorkbenchPartReference partRef) {

    if (!partRef.getClass().getName().equals("org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference")) {
        System.out.println("partDeactivated: not a Editor="+partRef.getClass().getName());
        return;
    }

    if (!editor.isDirty()) {
        // if the editor is not dirty - do nothing
        return;
    }

    Display.getDefault().asyncExec(() ->
      {
        // TODO the rest of your deactivate code goes here
      });
}
```

(Above code assumes you are using Java 8 or later)

This is 3.x compatibility mode code, not e4.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a great solution, using the suggestions above and [Enumerating all my Eclipse editors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516704/enumerating-all-my-eclipse-editors)
I am checking all editors first, then all persisted editors - skipping itself and the persisted objects.

Thanks for your comments!

```
public class ConceptAcronymValidator implements IValidator { 

    private ConceptInstanceEditor myEditor;

    public ConceptAcronymValidator(ConceptInstanceEditor editor) {
        super();
        this.myEditor = editor;
    }

    @Override
    public IStatus validate(Object value) {


        // check all Editors
        for (IEditorReference editorRef: PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getEditorReferences()) {
            IEditorPart editor = editorRef.getEditor(false);
            if (editor != null) {
                // don't check our own Editor
                if (!editor.equals(myEditor)) {
                    ConceptInstanceEditor conceptEditor = (ConceptInstanceEditor)editor;
                    if (conceptEditor.getTxtAcronym().equals(value.toString())) {
                        return ValidationStatus.error("This Concept is already used by Editor <"+
                                conceptEditor.getConceptModel().getName().getValue(MultilingualString.EN)+
                                ">");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // check all persisted Concepts
        List<Concept> concepts = ReferenceServiceFactory.getService().getConcepts();
        for (Concept concept: concepts) {
            Concept myConcept = (Concept) myEditor.getConceptModel().getInstance();
            // check if a new Editor
            if (myConcept == null) {
                if (concept.getAcronym().equals(value.toString())) {
                    return ValidationStatus.error("This Concept is already used by <"+
                            concept.getName().getValue(MultilingualString.EN)+
                            ">");
                }
            }
            else {
                // don't check own Instance
                if (!concept.equals(myConcept)) {
                    if (concept.getAcronym().equals(value.toString())) {
                        return ValidationStatus.error("This Concept is already used by <"+
                                concept.getName().getValue(MultilingualString.EN)+
                                ">");
                    }   
                }
            }
        }

        return Status.OK_STATUS;
    }
}
```